# React Redux Turbo Module Build Failed

Tags: html, reactjs, redux

I've been following this tutorial (https://www.turbo360.co/tutorial/redux-walkthrough) and I keep trying to run webpack but the build keeps failing. Any one know why it keeps crashing?

```
import { createStore, appMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { todoReducer } from './reducers'

let store = null
export default {

   createStore: () => {
      const reducers = combineReducers({
      todo: todoReducer
   })

   store = createStore(
      reducers
      appMiddleware(thunk)
   )

   return store
   },

   currentStore: () => {
      return store
   }

}
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: isn't it `applyMiddleware` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `applyMiddleware`, not `appMiddleware`. It's a typo.
[applyMiddleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html)